# cakephp saving data for a related model's related model (not typo)

Tags: cakephp-2.0, models, saving-data

I've run into a bit of a problem saving data in cake php.

here are the models/relationships.

- **District** hasMany **Departments**
- **Department** hasMany **Groups**

I am in a view for creating new district, in which I've allowed the user to create multiple new departments. while creating each department, the user may create multiple groups for that dept. Now the trouble is I'm unsure of how to save the group data.

for each department that is created on the fly, im using the multiple index method for the inputs (i.e. "Department.0.name", Department.0.type) so this will be a cinch to save using the saveAll method. However, for each group that is created, i will need a department_id, and since none of the District's departments have yet been saved, they don't have an id. how can i save this new district's data, saving the new departments, and their associated new created groups? is there a way that i can address the name attribute of the group inputs that will create the proper association, something like "Department.0.Group.0.name", for instance?

Thanks in advance!!! if anything is unclear, please don't hesitate to say so, I'll be glad to rephrase.

Answer (score 2):

What does your POST data array look like?

```
<?php

debug($this->data);

?>
```

If it is not in the correct format, the associated models won't get saved.. Cake knows to grab the "lastInsertId()" of the models which haven't been saved yet, so you don't have to worry about those... What i'm not sure about, and the docs don't really go into, is how deep the save goes.  The example provided is as follows:

```
$this->data =
Array
(
    [Article] => Array
        (
            [title] => My first article
        )
    [Comment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [comment] => Comment 1
                    [user_id] => 1
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [comment] => Comment 2
                    [user_id] => 2
                )
       )
)

$this->Article->saveAll($this->data);
```

This is the correct structure (cakephp 1.3) for saving associated models of a 'hasMany' relationship, but i'm not sure if it goes any deeper than one child.

One thing that comes to my mind is to build the array according to the format above, but leave the parent model out. Then manually save the parent model data, grab the ::getLastInsertId(); then do a saveAll on departments and groups.

---

[**UPDATE**]
I just tested your theory and it will work the way you intend.

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->input('Department.0.Group.0.name');

?>
```

Will produce:

```
<input name="data[Department][0][Group][0][name]" type="text" id="Department0Group0name">
```

[**UPDATE 2**]
I did some exploring in lib/Cake/Model/Model.php and found this:

```
<?php
...

public function saveAssociated($data = null, $options = array()) {
    ...
    ... // code omitted.
    ...
    if ($options['deep']) {  // This will recurse infinitely through all associations
        $saved = $this->{$association}->saveAssociated($values, array_merge($options, array('atomic' => false)));
    }
    ...
    ...
    ... // code omitted.
...
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! As, far as saveAll, as I understand it, it will save model data and associated model data. So, of the above, it would save all of that. saveAll is a wrapper for several save methods, one of which is saveAssociated(). As far as depth goes, to save data for associated models' associated models, i believe you could use saveAssociated($data, array('deep'=>true)). I'm creating the inputs manually for group inside a view of a district action. Could I set the name attribute to `<input name="data[Department][X][Group][X][attribute_name]" >`, i wonder?

Comment: That seems right, 'deep' => true huh?  I never used that, good idea.  I believe your input name is valid and I believe it will create the right structure.  

`<?php
   echo $this->Form->input('Modelname.0.fieldname');
   echo $this->Form->input('Modelname.1.fieldname');
?>

<input type="text" id="Modelname0Fieldname" name="data[Modelname][0][fieldname]">
<input type="text" id="Modelname1Fieldname" name="data[Modelname][1][fieldname]">`

Comment: Entity depth limitations
`In 1.2 there was a hard limit of 5 nested keys. This posed significant limitations on form input creation in some contexts. In 1.3 you can now create infinitely nested form element keys. Validation errors and value reading for arbitrary depths has also been added.` Looks like the limit is infinite :)

Comment: I'll have to see, then, if I can chain the data in a District controller view (using my example) like so: `<?php echo $this->Form->input('Department.0.Group.0.fieldname'); ?>`. then if I save the data via the saveAssociated($data, array('deep'=>true)), I wonder if cake will 'automagically' stick all of the right foreign key values in(i.e. the department_id)?

Comment: In response to your update: awesome! Now, the only all-important question remaining is, "will that save correctly," filling in all of the previously mentioned foreign keys?

Comment: You should change your tag to cakephp-2.0, or at least add it as a tag... I've been scanning the 1.3 docs, until you said "saveAssociated" and "deep" which is 2.0/2.1 specific.

Comment: updated tag as suggested what is your assessment on the use of that form helper (model.0.OtherModel.o.field)? Should it work?

Comment: I believe so, check out update 2. Or maybe I don't understand your final question :)

Comment: Hello again Todd, did you figure out your problem? If you feel the answer I provided helped in any way, please mark it as correct.

Thanks, have a good one!